# Am not Getting the exact path using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

doc_name="../Scripts/ResourceFiles/String_Client." + cookieCulture + ".json"
xhttp.open("GET", doc_name, false);
```

path now geting is

```
http://www.example.com:4568/Inventory/Scripts/ResourceFiles/String_Client." + cookieCulture + ".json"
```

but actually i need to get the path as `http://www.example.com:4568/Scripts/ResourceFiles/String_Client." + cookieCulture + ".json"`

Comment: if i got it right, u should not be using `../` is the doc_name then right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I'm getting exactly right what you're trying to do there, but simply using "/" at the beginning of the URL should always do the trick of pointing to the root:

```
doc_name="/Scripts/ResourceFiles/String_Client." + cookieCulture + ".json"
```